# c# Entity framework foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm new here and hope I'll get an answer - I'm searching the internet since two days ...

It's the first time I use the entity framewort in a Windows 10 UWP. I have to classes which are the objects for my database. In one object I use a property with the type of the other.
If I'll try to add a record I'll get a error.

```
public class budgetcontext : DbContext
{
    private string myDB = "Filename=budget_4.db";

    public DbSet<category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public budgetcontext()
    {
        this.Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(myDB);
    }
}

public class category
{
    private string myGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double BudgetDaily { get; set; }
    public double BudgetWeekly { get; set; }
    public double BudgetMonthly { get; set; }
    public double BudgetYearly { get; set; }

    public string CategoryGuid
    {
        get
        {
            return myGuid;
        }
    }

}

public class transaction
{
    private string myGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public category Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransDateTime { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to insert a record of the type transaction to the database I'll get the error:

*{"SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Categories.CategoryId'."}*

The code to insert the object is:

```
budget_sqlite.category c = cbCategory.SelectedItem as budget_sqlite.category; //Object is selected in a Combo

using (var db = new budget_sqlite.budgetcontext())
        {
            t.Text = this.txtText.Text;
            t.Category = c;
            t.TransDateTime = new DateTime(dpDate.Date.Year, dpDate.Date.Month, dpDate.Date.Day, tpTime.Time.Hours, tpTime.Time.Minutes, tpTime.Time.Seconds);

            double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out value);

            if (RBOut.IsChecked == true)
            {
                value = value * -1;
            }

            t.Amount = value;

            if (t.TransactionId == 0)
            {
                db.Transactions.Add(t);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here are the migrations:

```
[DbContext(typeof(budgetcontext))]
partial class budgetcontextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.1.0-rtm-22752");

        modelBuilder.Entity("budget_sqlite.category", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("CategoryId")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<double>("BudgetDaily");

                b.Property<double>("BudgetMonthly");

                b.Property<double>("BudgetWeekly");

                b.Property<double>("BudgetYearly");

                b.Property<string>("Name");

                b.HasKey("CategoryId");

                b.ToTable("Categories");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("budget_sqlite.transaction", b =>
            {
                b.Property<long>("TransactionId")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                b.Property<double>("Amount");

                b.Property<int?>("CategoryId");

                b.Property<string>("Text");

                b.Property<DateTime>("TransDateTime");

                b.HasKey("TransactionId");

                b.HasIndex("CategoryId");

                b.ToTable("Transactions");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("budget_sqlite.transaction", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("budget_sqlite.category", "Category")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("CategoryId");
            });
    }
}

public partial class V0001 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Categories",
            columns: table => new
            {
                CategoryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                BudgetDaily = table.Column<double>(nullable: false),
                BudgetMonthly = table.Column<double>(nullable: false),
                BudgetWeekly = table.Column<double>(nullable: false),
                BudgetYearly = table.Column<double>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Categories", x => x.CategoryId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Transactions",
            columns: table => new
            {
                TransactionId = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Amount = table.Column<double>(nullable: false),
                CategoryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                Text = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                TransDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Transactions", x => x.TransactionId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Transactions_Categories_CategoryId",
                    column: x => x.CategoryId,
                    principalTable: "Categories",
                    principalColumn: "CategoryId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Transactions_CategoryId",
            table: "Transactions",
            column: "CategoryId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Transactions");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Categories");
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The error clearly show whats wrong. You trying add Categories with exist CategoryId

Comment: I do not want to add the category - it should just be a reference to an existing category.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to solve the problem. The problem was that I used the object of type "Category" from another context.